# html3 audio element mp3 audio file isn't supported

Tags: html, audio, visual-studio-cordova

In Visual Studio Community 2017, I started with the "Ionic 2 - Sidemenu" template. (Angular2, Ionic2, TypeScript)  I want to use the html5 audio element and play an mp3 file stored locally, so I have this in the html

```
<ion-content padding>
    <ion-card>
      <ion-card-header>
          Play Mp3
      </ion-card-header>
      <audio controls></audio>
      <br />
      <button ion-button round (click)="setSrc()">Load File</button>
    </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

I start the app as Windows-x86, Local Machine, on my Windows 10 PC. The code loads the audio file on a button click to make sure deviceReady has fired. This is everything in the .ts file.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
@Component({
    selector: 'page-page1',
    templateUrl: 'the-player.html'
})
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
export class ThePlayer {
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    }    
    setSrc() {
        var myPlayer = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];
        // the intellisense verifies that this path is correct
        myPlayer.src = '../../audio/Capitolo_7s.mp3';   // no Cannot-set-src-of-undefined error is thrown
    }
    onLink(url: string) {
        window.open(url);
    }
}
```

After setSrc() runs this displays next to the player's play button in the UI.

> This type of audio file isn't supported

I need to be able to control the speed of the playback and have not found that method on a cordova plugin, so that is why I want to use an audio element.  I know the mp3 file is fine.  I can dbl click it in File Explorer and it plays fine.

Ideas?

Comment: Could you please try other mp3 files? If the problem persists, could you share a basic demo that can reproduce the problem?

Comment: I tried another mp3 file and got the same results.